# Error Plotting graph in R on the columns of MySql DB

Tags: mysql, sql, r, plot

Hi i am trying to plot a graph on the below result got from my database.

```
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT emp_name , count(emp_no) as count FROM employees.sample where salary>1000 group by emp_no;")
data <- fetch(rs)

>data

    emp_name count
1    emp1     3
2    emp2     2
3    emp3     2
4    emp4     3
5    emp5     2
```

When running:

```
plot(data)
```

I am getting the below error

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Edited your answer to make it more clear:

Assuming you want a barplot:

```
barplot(height=data$count,names.arg = data$emp_name)
```

[image]